# How to resize the app icons in the app picker in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell, 22.04

I'm using a 1366x768 desktop, and the GNOME app picker (app drawer) is reducing the size of the icons, even though there is plenty of space to fit everything. In addition to that, the names of the applications are also truncated.

[image: Screenshot of the reduced size]

This seemed to be an issue with GNOME 40.alpha, which one would expect to have been fixed with GNOME 42
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3465.

The issue resolves itself if I move the dock to the bottom.

[image: Screenshot of the expected size of the icons in the app drawer]

I couldn't find any configuration for the same in `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`.

If you could help, then I'd be very thankful.